# How do I know if my Bootstrap Juju installed juju-gui?

Tags: juju, conjure-up

Finally got my bootstrap to work on a metal node in maas.

How do I know if the bootstrap installed juju-gui?

It doesnt show in a "juju status", so guessing it didnt?

Using Ubuntu 18.04lts and a snap installed juju.

Looking to attempt a conjure-up install of openstack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `juju gui` command.

```
$ juju gui
GUI 2.14.0 for model "admin/default" is enabled at:
https://x.x.x.x:17070/gui/u/admin/default
Your login credential is:
    username: admin
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```